# What does {z}/{x}/{y} mean in "tiles": [location.origin+location.pathname+"countries/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf"],

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and am trying to figure out the the syntax of some code. Have tried googling for similar questions but can't seem to find any relevant ones. Perhaps I have not been using the right keywords for my search :(

I am trying to understand the code from:

https://github.com/klokantech/mapbox-gl-js-offline-example/blob/gh-pages/index.html

Here's an excerpt of the code:

```
<script>
// mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.your-own-code-here-for-online-maps';
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'NOT-REQUIRED-WITH-YOUR-VECTOR-TILES-DATA';
var style = {
  "version": 8,
  "sources": {
    "countries": {
      "type": "vector",
      // "url": "mapbox://map-id"
      // "url": "http://tileserver.com/layer.json", 
      "tiles": [location.origin+location.pathname+"countries/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf"],
      "maxzoom": 6
    }
  },
```

The line of the code that I am trying to understand is that as described in the title of this question.

Can someone explain it to me, please?

Thanks much.

Comment: Seems like placeholders to be later replaced, e.g. as simple as `style.sources.countries.titles.replace('{x}', 123)`

Comment: Zoom and the X & Y position of the requested tile.  Basically it's a simplified template replacement used by mapbox.  You might have tiles stored in a different url format, and this allows you to let mapbox know what that is.

Comment: @mbojko But it's not ES6 literals, please don't confuse OP with *elephant similar to dog, because it has 4 legs*

Comment: To get a better understanding of what the Z/X/Y values do, try opening https://www.openstreetmap.org wait for it to load, now in dev tools open up the network tab, clear the network log, now scroll around and zoom in/out etc, you will notice lots of Png files appear.   If you look at one of these URL it might show something like -> `https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/17/66371/45091.png`  So here {z} = 17 (zoom), {x} = 66371, & {y} = 45091,  so for mapbox you could do -> `https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`.  Virtual cookie for the first to work out what I was looking at.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are just (sub)strings that are later replaced by corresponding values. By themselves, they don't have any meaning or functionality.

[Mapbox Style Specification](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#sources) leads to [TileJSON specification](https://github.com/mapbox/tilejson-spec/tree/master/2.2.0) which says:

> [..] {z}, {x} and {y}, if present, are replaced with the corresponding integers.

The library will then likely do something along the lines of:

```
let url = "{x}/{y}/{z}".replace( "{x}", 1337 ).replace("{y}", -99).replace("{z}", 1.333)
```

where instead of the number literals, you would of course use variables in real-world settings.

Comment: Thanks for the clear and concise reply! I do not have a high enough reputation yet, or I would have given you an upvote.

Comment: just did that :)